# why is system.img.ext4 generated after building Android ICS?

Tags: android, linux, boot, android-build

While Building Android ICS, system.img and system.img.ext4 are generated. Why are 2 such images generated? do I need to flash both of them to have ICS running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need to flash only system.img.

Comment: Thanks. Im still wondering though why system.img.ext4 is generated. Is any documentation available on android build procedure? In general or specifically for ICS?

Comment: Its simple, system.img.ext4 is generated to enable android on a ext4 filesystem while system.img is for yaffs2 filesystem. Most devices use yaffs2 filesystem as default, hence we end up flashing system.img instead of ext4.